# Sending and receiving information from an HTML5 page via a serial port

Tags: html, serial-port, rs485

I have to make a HTML5 page to run on a handheld console that communicates information through a RS485 serial port (which is an industrial version of the RS232, if I am right!).

I wonder which programming language can I use to send or receive information from my HTML5 page to the serial port RS485? I look forward to your responses.

Comment: I think you're most likely looking at an ActiveX or Java plugin, which has not much to do with HTML 5 though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that you want to interface with the Serial Port on the console then you should probably use JavaScript. I'm not sure if any modern browser will allow you to to be honest. If you mean on the server then you could use PHP and use this [PHP-Serial Interface](http://code.google.com/p/php-serial/).

If you are trying to do it on the device then my only suggestion would be to somehow install a web server on the device again use the PHP-Serial interface.